# Embedding an AVI/MPG in a Web Page

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails, html

I would like to play a video (AVI/MPG) on a PHP page.  How can I do this?  I would also like to generate thumbnails for each video.  Could anyone suggest some tools?

Answer (score 3):

For thumbnails you'd need something like [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469821/what-is-the-better-way-to-create-thumbnails-from-video-in-php) installed on your server.

To play the videos, you could use any javascript media player or HTML5, there are a ton of free ones or the web such as [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)

Comment: Please help me with
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279935/how-to-form-a-php-tree-menu/8279985#8279985

Answer (score 1):

Just like Kevin said, you need ffmpeg installed on your server to generate thumbnails. Have a look [here](http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/) - hope it gets you started.

Comment: Thanks!! Could you please help me some problem with PHP links I have been facing... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279935/how-to-form-a-php-tree-menu/8279985#8279985